# Making locators dynamic in XCUITest

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcuitest, xcuielement

Is it possible to make locators dynamic in XCUITest? generally when defining a locator we tend to write as:
let optionAbutton = app.buttons["option-a"]

And use it in func as optionAbutton.tap();

Now, if there are more buttons on the page like: option-b, option-c should we have separate locators for each like:
let optionBbutton = app.buttons["option-b"]
let optionCbutton = app.buttons["option-c"]

Or is it possible to keep the locator generic like app.buttons["PLACEHOLDER"] and replace it with option-a, option-b or option-c inside the func?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course. The identifier is simply a string so any amount of string manipulation is permitted.

```
func tapAnOptionButton(suffix: String) {
  anOptionButton(suffix).tap()
}

private func anOptionButton(_ suffix: String) -> XCUIElement {
  return app.buttons[“option-“ + suffix]
}
```

And then to use it:

```
tapAnOptionButton(suffix: “a”)
```